# How to implement a drag/drop gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I am new to python and am looking to write a simple GUI for a script I wrote. I would need to be able to drag/drop boxes within a window. i.e. I would have a blank field and under it a list of options represented by different boxes. I would then want to be able to drag the options in the filed and list them in it as they are added. I know this is relatively easy do to in javascript using jQuery but I am not doing a web application. Which python gui framework would allow me to do this drag/drop easily ? Tkinter, pyQT, wxPython ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a GUI design app for the Tkinter / grid geometry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142194/is-there-a-gui-design-app-for-the-tkinter-grid-geometry)

Answer (score 0):

wxPython with:

1. [Boa Constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/) - [Example](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=4010000&fromSeriesID=401)
2. [wxDesigner](http://www.roebling.de/sshots.html)

Theres also qt bindings with pyqt and pyside, where you could use QT Creator to Design your applications.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Rapyd](http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/) for python development with Tkinter.

This is an open-source development environment for developing applications using Python, Tkinter and, optionally, Pmw.